# Sed, Awk for combining the output of two cut statements

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to combine the below outputs into one command. The issue is that the field I'm trying to grab is in reverse order. I was told that cut doesn't support a "reverse" option and to use AWK for this purpose but it didn't end up working for my purpose. I'm trying to take the output of the ls- l against the /dev/block to return the partitions and automatically build a dd if= / of= for each outputted line based on the output of the command.

I tried piping the output to awk:

```
cut -d' ' -f23,25 ... | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

however, the result was when using sed to input the prefix and suffix, it wasn't in the appropriate order.

I built the two statements below which individually return the expected output, just looking for the "right" way to combine both of these statements in the most efficient manner using sed / awk.

```
ls -l /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/ | cut -d' ' -f 25 | sed "s/^/dd if=/"


ls -l /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/ | cut -d' ' -f 23 | sed "s/.*/of=\/external_sd\/&.dsk/"
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Show sample output of `ls -l /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/` and your desired output for that sample input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using `awk`, I don't think you'll need `cut` or `sed`.  You can probably do something like the following, though I'll have to trust you on the field numbers

```
ls -l /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name | awk '{print "dd if=/"$25 " of=/" $23 ".dsk"}'
```

awk will split on all whitespace, not just the space character, so it's possible the fields will shift some, though it may be more reliable too.

Comment: Thanks Eric, awk '{print "dd if=/"$8 " of=/" $6 ".dsk"}' Ended up doing the job, just had to account for the split on both whitespace and space. Thanks again!